# Per-thread hashtable-like data structure implementation in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing

Short version of my question:
I have a CUDA program where each thread needs to store numbers in different "bins", and I identify each of these bins by an integer. For a typical run of my program, each CUDA thread might only store numbers in 100 out of millions of bins, so I'd like to know if there is a data structure other than an array that would allow me to hold this data. Each thread would have its own copy of this structure. If I were programming in Python, I would just use a dictionary where the bin numbers are the keys, for example mydict[0] = 1.0, mydict[2327632] = 3.0, and then at the end of the run I would look at the keys and do something with them (and ignore the bins where no numbers are stored in them since they aren't in the dictionary). I tried implementing a hash table for every thread in my cuda program and it killed performance.

Long version:
I have a CUDA Monte Carlo simulation which simulates the transport of particles through a voxelized (simple volume elements) geometry. The particles deposit energy during their transport and this energy is tallied on a voxel-per-voxel basis. The voxels are represented as a linearized 3D grid which is quite large, around 180^3 elements. Each CUDA thread transports 1-100 particles and I usually try to maximize the number of threads that I spawn my kernel with. (Currently, I use 384*512 threads). The energy deposited in a given voxel is added to the linearized 3d grid which resides in global memory through atomicAdd.

I'm running into some problems with a part of my simulation which involves calculating uncertainties in my simulation. For a given particle, I have to keep track of where (which voxel indices) it deposits energy, and how much energy for a given voxel, so that I can square this number at the end of the particle transport before moving on to a new particle. Since I assign each thread one (or a few) particle, this information has to be stored at a per-thread scope. The reason I only run into this problem with uncertainty calculation is that energy deposition can just be done as an atomic operation to a global variable every time a thread has to deposit energy, but uncertainty calculation has to be done at the end of a particle's transport, so I have to somehow have each thread keep track of the "history" of their assigned particles.

My first idea was to implement a hash table whose key would be the linearized voxel index, and value would be energy deposited, and I would just square every element in that hash table and add it to a global uncertainty grid after a particle is done transporting. I tried to implement uthash but it destroyed the performance of my code. I'm guessing it caused a huge amount of thread divergence.

I could simply use two dynamic arrays where one stores the voxel index and the other would store the energy deposited for that voxel, but I am thinking that it would also be very bad for performance. I'm hoping that there is a data structure that I don't know about which would lend itself well to being used in a CUDA program. I also tried to include many details in case I am completely wrong in my approach to the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit jargon-ful.  If you can distill out the science and leave just the computer science, you might get more answers.

There have been [CUDA hash tables implemented](http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~dfalcant/research/hashing.php).  The work at that link will be included in the 2.0 release of the [CUDPP library](http://cudpp.googlecode.com).  It is already working in the [SVN trunk of CUDPP](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/source/checkout), if you would like to try it.

That said, if you really only need per-thread storage, and not shared storage, you might be able to do something much simpler, like some per-thread scratch space (in shared or global memory) or a local array.

Comment: Sorry for the jargon, I added a shorter and more concise version of my question. I made a working version with local arrays but it slowed down my program by 400%, not as bad as the hash table I did, but still a bit unacceptable. It really has to be local storage.

Comment: I would use a global hash table like the one I referred to in CUDPP (a multivalue hash table, specifically).  But you will need to identify each threads' data uniquely.  Perhaps you could use the upper bits of a stored int to identify the thread, and use the lower bits as a pointer / index.